# Get path of open directory in command prompt in a batch file

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am creating a custom command, and it requires the batch file to know the path of the directory open in the command prompt that the command is run on. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

To find out the current path, check `%cd%`

Here is an example:

```
C:\>cd /d D:\temp

D:\temp>echo %cd%
D:\temp

D:\temp>
```

Given that this path changes, you can save it at the start of the batch file by using:

```
set startdir=%cd%
```

Now you can see what `%startdir%` is in order to get that path.

If you want to know what the path is in which your batch file is located, then you can use the %0 variable, which contains the entire path plus filename of the batch file, as such:

```
set scriptdir=%~dp0
```

Comment: I'd prefer using `set scriptdir=%~dp0`

Comment: @LotPings depends on what you want, they are 3 different folders.

Comment: If you want to store the script location and underhand change the drive (implict with cd /d) , the stored script location maybe invalid with the then current drive.

Comment: @LotPings, no. Why would it? The path does include the driveletter.

Comment: @LotPings ah, I see the typo I made.

Comment: How can i open up the dir of a random file (open folder from path)